# Sybase assigning datatype to variable?

Tags: sql, variables, types, sybase, netezza

Hello I don't quite understand this syntax could someone explain me what this does to the variable x?  Variable x is defined as  `x VARCHAR(250);`

`SET x= res || CHAR(39)`

or `SET x= CHAR(39)`

Im trying to convert this sybase line to Netezza and this far netezze dont like this syntax: 
`X:=CHAR(39)`
and this throws me "**SELECT  CHAR(39)'
error                   ^ found "" (at char 16) expecting `SCONST'**"  ERROR

EDIT:
is `SET x = CHAR(5)`  same as `SET x = '     '` ??

Comment: In what environment are you trying to execute the assignment of a variable? A stored procedure, the NZSQL CLI, or through an ODBC/OLE-DB/JDBC connection?

Comment: Did you try CHR(39) ?

Comment: Assuming it's in Sybase ASE, <number> in CHAR(<number>) is the ascii number. So, CHAR(39) turns to single quote. variable x gets that value.